# Showing number of features in Contents pane of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, contents-pane

Is it possible to show the number of features per category in the Contents pane of ArcGIS Pro?

It is simple to do in QGIS, but in ArcGIS Pro I only found the possibility to retrieve the number of features per category within the Symbology pane.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you can see the number of features selected per TOC layer on the selection tab, I do not know of any way to do so without using feature selection.
 [image: Feature layer selection count]

Answer (score 1):

One method to do this is to create a Layout, add your Map Frame to your Layout, and then add a Legend to your layout with "Show feature counts" checked:

[image: New Layout, Add Map Frame, Add Legend, Show Legend Properties...]

[image: Show Feature Counts]

Then you can simply switch between your active map and layout map, or leave them open side by side, to see the number of features in your layers. This will be dynamic as long as you leave the default "Synchronize with map" options checked. You can beautify the legend if this will be a permanent fixture of your editing:

[image: Map synchronized with Layout/Legend]